# Use ENS with MyEtherWallet.com

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, ens

When starting an auction for an .eth address on MyEtherWallet.com am I automatically placing a bid on the address or do I have to manually place a bid afterwards (and pay 0.01 ETH AGAIN)?

Comment: Are you talking about each step of the ENS bidding or what the bid disguise is?

Answer (score 0):

There is no start auction fee (beyond the gas costs). The amount that you put in "Actual Bid Amount" is the amount that you're bidding on the name.

If everything succeeds in that transaction, then you do not need to make a separate bid.